# An ActionScript file must have at least one externally visible definition

Tags: actionscript-3

My main timeline code reads

```
var BlueBox:MovieClip = new bluebox(); 

include "bluebox.as";
```

My AS file reads

```
addChild(BlueBox);
```

I am getting weird errors, the documentation I read on flash's website said you can include ActionScript in an AS file as if it were on the timeline with the include function or with `<mx:Script source="Box.as" />` however I am getting an error about classes or something irrelevant nonsense. I am not trying to include a class, just trying to include the AS file.

`Line 1 5007: An ActionScript file must have at least one externally visible definition.`

Comment: What happens if you declare `var BlueBox` inside the AS file itself? Anyways `bluebox.as` must contain a line like `public class bluebox { ... your code ... }` to have one _"one externally visible definition"_.

Comment: returns "classes must not be nested" it's not a class, I dont understand what's so complicated here, refuses to load the file unless I define it as a class, and then when I do it refuses to load

Comment: I hear you but your error expects it to be setup like a class file (eg: don't just throw one string in there `addChild(BlueBox);` and expect it to work)... That's why I suggest defining the var in same AS file so the compiler isn't confused by null variables (which really exist in another scope like timeline). PS Why not use `import` for classes of AS code?

Comment: storing code in AS files

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fbb.html

I have no idea why adobe refuses to include any kind of example in these topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out finally
just add a function definition in AS file

```
choosefunctionname(); // to execute function of code

function choosefunctionname(): void
{
   //code here
}
```

Comment: Upvote for solving it yourself. Please also mark as correct answer to help future readers. Thanks.

Comment: I have to wait another 24 hours to do so but I will when I can, thanks